# What is the KP+ key?

Tags: discussion, answers

I don't know how to reply directly to the answer..

https://askubuntu.com/a/7186

What is this person talking about? When I press Ctrl + Alt + K + P + '+'(Shift + '=') nothing happens. It's all in one box, is it a single key called "KP+"?

How do you reply directly to an answer? Just edit it? Is it ok that I made a new question about a different question? Should I have added an answer to the original question with my response?

These keywords are being broken up strangely. How many characters do you need to delimiter individual keywords?

That dang 'existing tag' link took me away from this page. Wouldn't that have been bad if the browser didn't store this form data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`KP+` means the `+` key on the numeric keypad, KP = KeyPad

Comment: Thanks, was it correct to make a new question? Should I be making new questions every time I have additional questions about answers? Should this reply have been a new question somewhere?

Comment: Stick around, answer a few questions and earn 50+ reputation points.  Then you can comment on questions and answers to ask for clarification.

Comment: In the meantime though, I shouldn't ask questions about answers at all? That's been 100% of what I've wanted to do every time I come here after a Google search.

Comment: @user988346 You should not ask a new question, nor should you create an answer to answer anothers' question; answers are not stored or displayed in  certain order.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ That they are not displayed in an order only affects the readability of my response. Are you telling me that the intention is that I am simply not supposed to respond to answers at all, or that I am not supposed to respond to answers and have them be in a sensible order?
----
If the goal is to have noobies post their responses up and down the page, just not in the comments field, then I can do that until I have enough points to use the field.
----
This comment field drops all my new lines... and multiple spaces...

Comment: @user988346 I'm not really saying either. I'm saying that if you add an answer referring to one posted previously, it may end up somewhere else on the page, not in the position you may want it in. You should respond to answers, but you should use a comment on that answer. Any uses of answers or questions to respond to existing answers may be flagged by users so a mod can convert to a comment, gratis. Once you get 50 rep, you can post comments, with a once-every-15-sec limitation. We really don't have too much of an issue with misuse of answers. They get flagged pretty quickly.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ Sweet, thanks. That was most of my question. So.. I won't get banned for posting answers that are actually responses to other people's answers and comments? That's just what I have to do until I get 50 rep?

Comment: @user988346 While you *can*, it makes moderating the site a pain, and I'd refrain from it. It's mainly users who accidentally do it that get post conversions. You can get a possible suspension if you have enough infractions. I myself disagree with the 50-rep requirement to comment. Sorry.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ Well, ok. Thanks for the help.